# Check/uncheck a checkbox in the table row when any checkbox in the same row is clicked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a simple table as following which has checkboxes in the first and last columns of each row.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Problem: 
When I check/uncheck the last column's checkbox in the first row, the first column's checkbox in the same row should be checked/unchecked. Similarly, if I check/uncheck the first column's checkbox, the corresponding last column checkbox should be checked/unchecked.

How can I achieve this in javascript? Any help or pointers would be really appreciated.

Here is the fiddle which I have created: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89xt4qhu/2/)

Thank you.

Comment: @RayonDabre I wanted to do it in JavaScript. But sure, jQuery should be great.

Comment: You may take a look at this Javascript solution and modify the Row's onClick event per your purpose: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/209416/Click-select-row-in-ASP-NET-GridView-or-HTML-Table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Use `:checkbox` selector to select input type `checkbox` elements.

Try this:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Using JavaScript:**

> Use `querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]')` to find `checkbox` elements.

Try this:

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
[].forEach.call(checkboxes, function(checkbox) {
  checkbox.onchange = function() {
    var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cbElems = currentRow.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
    [].forEach.call(cbElems, function(cb) {
      cb.checked = this.checked;
    }.bind(this))
  };
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't think of the closest at all! That was a fantastic answer! Thanks a lot! I was wondering how I could do it in JavaScript! Any pointers for that?

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot @RayonDabre

Comment: Instead of passing the ":checkbox" or type="checkbox", can we give an id to the input type and achieve the same? I tried it out, it didn't work though!

Comment: When you talk about `id`, they must be unique.. And that is the reason one should not go with `ids` when dealing with `n` number of elements of same kind.. __Yes__, It is possible but why do you really need it ?

Comment: True. Sorry not the id, a "class". Just curious. Nothing else :)

Comment: Yes..You can deal with `classes`

Comment: `'input[type="checkbox"].myclass'` would select those with that class; pretty much the same answer I was typing otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

One possible `Javascript` solution to toggle `Checkboxes` on Table `Row` click is shown below:

**HTML**

```
<table id = "Table1">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>John Smith</td> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Anna Warner</td> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table, th, td{
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{width:100%;}
```

**Javascript**

```
   // row click will toggle checkboxes
   row_OnClick("Table1")
   function row_OnClick(tblId) {
    try {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tblId).rows;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var _row = rows[i];
            _row.onclick = null;
            _row.onclick = function () {
                return function () {selectRow(this);};
            }(_row);
        }
    }
    catch (err) { }
}
function selectRow(row) {
   row.cells[0].firstChild.checked = !row.cells[0].firstChild.checked;
   row.cells[2].firstChild.checked = row.cells[0].firstChild.checked;
}
```

Working jsfiddle demo at: https://jsfiddle.net/t6nsxgnz/
Practical implementation at: http://busny.net

You can further customize this solution pertinent to your task by modifying the `selectRow(row)` function:

```
function selectRow(row) {
   row.cells[0].firstChild.checked = // add your code for the 1st CheckBox
   row.cells[2].firstChild.checked = // add your code for the 2nd CheckBox
}
```

Another variation of this functionality coded in jQuery can be found in online pop-quiz engine (http://webinfocentral.com), implemented via the follwoing code snippet:

```
// toggle Checkboxes on row click
$(Table1 tr').click(function (event) {

    // find the checkbox in the row
    var _chk = $(this).find('input:checkbox');


    if (!($(event.target).is("checkbox"))) {
        $(_chk).prop('checked', !$(_chk).prop('checked'));
    }
});
```

In this case, `Row` `Click` (at any place of the `Row`) or CheckBox `Click` events will toggle the state of that particular `CheckBox`. The state of other CheckBoxes can be synchronized with this one (by using "siblings" property, for example).
Hope this may help.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Your code works great. But I think there is a small problem,  In the first column, the click works on the row, but not on the checkbox. If I click in the empty space of the column, the checkbox is getting checked. If I try to click on the checkbox, the checkbox isn't getting checked. But coming to the last column, the click on the checkbox is working! weird :P

Comment: You are welcome. This is just a demo sample, which could be further customized using the core coding technique I've described (see my extended answer). Best regards,