# Uncheck checkbox in same row kendo grid at button press

Tags: javascript, button, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I have a Kendo Grid with multiple columns.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridViewModel>()
                  .Name("Docgrid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(c => c.read).Template("<input type='checkbox' #= IsUnread ? checked='checked': '' # class='chkbx' />");
/* some more columns */
                      columns.Command(cmd =>{cmd.Custom("Download").Click("download");});
```

When I press the Downloadbutton I want to unselect the checkbox in the same grid row.

right now I only managed to unselect all checkboxes

[Check/uncheck a checkbox in the table row when any checkbox in the same row is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266769/check-uncheck-a-checkbox-in-the-table-row-when-any-checkbox-in-the-same-row-is-c) I found this but I wasn't able to adapt it to my needs using a button.

```
 $("#Download").click(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
```

This code will select any checkbox in the button#download row. Demo below:

```js
$("#download").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" id="download">Download"</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the demo I used an ordinary table, but it should work in a Kendo table as well. Make sure to change the `input[type='checkbox']` selector in case you want to change only one checkbox in the same row.

Comment: works fine, had another solution in the meantime, but tried yours as well and does the job! Thanks